# Searching into an array of NSManagedObjects

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate, nsmanagedobject

Suppose I have already retrieved an array of managed objects (an array of `Car` objects).  Lets say a `Car` has attributes like `make` and `model`. `Car`s are currently in an `NSArray`.

How can I find all cars with `honda` value for `make` attribute?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at `NSPredicate` for this [Using Predicates with Key-Paths](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pUsing.html)

So, for example:

```
NSString *trendName = @"honda";
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
        @"trend like %@", trendName]; // or "trend == %@"

NSArray *filteredArray = [results filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

where `trend` is a string property for your `Car` managed object.

Comment: awesome, didnt know you could use nspredicate even when not searching in coredata

Comment: @waf04 P.S. trend is equal to make. I didn't notice the first time. ;)

Comment: what if car has an nsset of carparts and I want to find a car matching a certain carpart.   So car a has toCarParts (wheel,tire,etc...) how do I build the predicate to look in there?

Comment: does this look right?  NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY toCarParts.name == [c] %@", carPartString];

Comment: @Will Yes. Did you try it?

Answer (score 2):

Use [NSPredicate](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPredicate_Class/Reference/NSPredicate.html) to search/filter trough the array.

```
NSString *modelName = @"honda";
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"model == %@", modelName];
NSArray *filteredArray = [results filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

Comment: Remove the comment at the end of predicate line ;-) Cheers